# Update Elastic search nested index value

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I had an index in the elastic search which has nested values, I want to update a value in nested index with Id, how can I achieve that. My index is like

```
{
    "took": 2,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 1,
        "max_score": 1.0,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "a",
                "_type": "a1",
                "_id": "my-index1",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "id": "my-index1",
                    "name": "firstIndex",
                    "metals": [
                        {
                            "id": "123",
                            "name": "Ronni",   
                        },
                         {
                            "id": "124",
                            "name": "Ross",   
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

How to update "Ross" with "Monika" with help of "Id"-124?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `metals` are of the [`nested` datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) (and not being just a trivially nested array), you can first constrict the docs-to-update using a [nested](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html) term query and then use a looped [script](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting-using.html) to execute your changes:

```
POST my-index1/_update_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "metals",
      "query": {
        "term": {
          "metals.id": "124"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "script": {
    "source": """
      for (def i = 0; i < ctx._source.metals.length; i++) {
        def group = ctx._source.metals[i];
        if (group['id'] == params['old_metal_id']) {
          ctx._source.metals[i]['name'] = params['new_metal_name']
        }

      }
    """,
    "params": {
      "old_metal_id": "124",
      "new_metal_name": "Monika"
    }
  }
}
```